# Duplicate identifier 'alpha'.deno-ts(2300) Unexpected keyword or identifier

Tags: npm, deno, alpha-vantage, skypack-cdn

I am trying to use `Alpha Vantage` NPM package inside my Deno application. I tried to use [SkyPack](https://www.skypack.dev/view/alphavantage-ts) version of it. But it gives me the following error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'alpha'.deno-ts(2300)
Unexpected keyword or identifier.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import alphavantageTs from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/alphavantage-ts';

export class StockTimeSeries{
        alpha = new alphavantageTs ("ASLDVIWXGEWFWNZG");

        alpha.stocks.intraday("msft").then((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            });
        
        alpha.stocks.batch(["msft", "aapl"]).then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        });
    
        alpha.forex.rate("btc", "usd").then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        });
    
        alpha.crypto.intraday("btc", "usd").then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        });
    
        alpha.technicals.sma("msft", "daily", 60, "close").then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        });
    
        alpha.sectors.performance().then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        });
   

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @jsejcksn: I don't know why do I get the errors and how can I get ride of them?

Comment: The syntax in your example is not valid TS or JS. Did you mean for all of that code in the class to be in its constructor?

Comment: @jsejcksn: I found that code from here: https://www.skypack.dev/view/alphavantage-ts  I thought it's a working example.

Comment: @jsejcksn: Do you know how can I modify and make it work? I am new in TS and Deno.

Comment: That module was not written to be used with Deno. It was written for Node. Not all Node modules can work with Deno (_most_ can't).

Comment: @jsejcksn: So you say at the moment I must forget using this library?

Comment: Unless you can find another source than SkyPack to make it work, then yes. (The API is just a simple REST endpoint), and it doesn't look like that module even provides any endpoint types (and it was last updated in 2018).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SkyPack is responding with a `401` for one of the sub-dependencies for that module. I'm also not even sure it's compatible with Deno.

That said, [here's the repo source](https://github.com/notadamking/alphavantage-ts) for the module, and [here's the documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for the API. It looks like it's just a simple REST API which discriminates requests by query parameters, so you can make your own Deno client without too much effort using that module as a template. I'll give you some starter code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKBDKGC2BnOAXjgDkIA7EgVwBsaMAjG4AHgGEK8YoqBjGaJmw5gMYFDwskKCADM4AVQBKAGQDKwLLwAWQ3HgB8AbQAMAXQMBuAFDXe9PAQCCNMNowA1DORgYA5sAkanAA3nC8nNx8AlBwABRgUBBi-MAAJnBQmmkUNIhwGGAAlgBccC6F7l4+-sAAlKEAvnCNtvYYjnAAYtCgcKBi5GnOrlXevgFBodZwmRhi8bJJOAD6vFRQWeS8iGVcUEXkfgA0CBBrG1s7e9yHfg0hM7OZohvkCNpFeAB0hUXfAEcqOJEHFHs9nrIqNsYEUKGUAORsZRKACiJDYAE0VqiABpsAASThIAHFUSslE4ACqohHHJ4QpYQVbrTbAbaIekQ2YCC5sjlc56NOo2WatVrWUCQWDhBwjSqeca1aazADEAgA1uybgcjjYnhFyPtotB4prtXB9ncHgyPl9vuqIFr3sRzeRRS1bLMOohtnAgSC4CwlMA8LR4MRvIgDAksPoynp8HUE8svqwQ2GaDADCrnoauHANjQiHByMAAO6KVRxBHaGAwMB4EoAemb5fbv1GGAAbkqAt8Is2A1BEAiRV685FC3gwCWy5XlOpNFAdIm8LHhHhxxCqDPvnhRDW-lrR6cYJ8fo7ndvnkX98udCXd2BvgI1LcjnFx7b8-AsgGC2Iec4BDACYDiO9tCyWQb1mX8XhnThUEjcsMCKeBZFEHQ4n-YEuG-CEinkOIAEIskQo1gG+J0GnPJJK2A1FNmgGsM0gSjS2SOAAHkAGkx31CEshgN4EPYg9vgAKzwCgvw9CVZlkXoQDnCtumUuJzy+ccJWsVtFAPEo2inTFuOUFYnDQABJFZeNRTESwRNJgBwCAERseCMC7VTKwqNxFRqAI4lM8zLJsuzMXHLz-O+JSshAb5sDEGsACEqTYOk4ARBQ1AAETHV9tHZOI0nmDAiBzfMIGYb4aAgPwSrKupxyAA)

```ts
export type Params = NonNullable<ConstructorParameters<typeof URLSearchParams>[0]>;

class AlphaVantageNS { constructor (protected readonly api: AlaphaVantage) {} }

class Forex extends AlphaVantageNS {
  rate (from_currency: string, to_currency: string) {
    return this.api.query({
      function: 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
      from_currency,
      to_currency,
    });
  }
}

export class AlaphaVantage {
  #token: string;

  constructor (token: string) {
    this.#token = token;
  }

  async query <Result = any>(params: Params): Promise<Result> {
    const url = new URL('https://www.alphavantage.co/query');

    const usp = new URLSearchParams(params);
    usp.set('apikey', this.#token);
    url.search = usp.toString();

    const request = new Request(url.href);
    const response = await fetch(request);

    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Response not OK');

    return response.json();
  }

  forex = new Forex(this);
}


// Use:

const YOUR_API_KEY = 'demo';
const alpha = new AlaphaVantage(YOUR_API_KEY);
alpha.forex.rate('BTC', 'USD').then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You did a GRET job for me!

Comment: Can I ask what does this line of code do? `export type Params = NonNullable<ConstructorParameters<typeof URLSearchParams>[0]>;`

Comment: It uses some [type utilities](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to create a type which represents the types of values that can be provided as the first argument to the [`URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor (excluding `null` and `undefined`).

Comment: Did you write all of this code yourself or you could find it/modify it from somewhere else? Because I like to know where can I find more information and learn more about it.

Comment: I wrote it in response to your question.